# como posso fazer uma div se esconder na lateral e quando clicada aparecer na tela?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Como posso fazer a div se esconder na lateral da tela? repare no menu lateral desse site http://preview.imithemes.com/?theme=Solicitor-WP tentei de um modo mas não foi alguém sabe um meio? o meu coloquei display none e no js coloco block, porém tenho sempre que voltar para none depois se não as telas ficam bloqueadas, para piorar o botão do menu gera um atraso para voltar, ou seja quando a div volta para se esconder no animate o botão não volta colado nela, tem algum modo de deixar isso mais elegante?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function modalOpen(){
            $(document).ready(function(e){
            tamanho = $('.modal-box').css("width");
             $("#box1").animate({right: '0px'});
             $("#botao").animate({right: tamanho});
             $('#modal').css("display","block");

            /*FECHAR O MODAL SE O BOTÃO CANCELAR FOR PRESSIONADO */
            $('.cancel, #modal').click(function(event){
                if(event.target !== this){
                    return;
                }
                 $("#botao").animate({right: '0px'});
                
                 setTimeout(function() {  $("#box1").animate({right: '-410px'}); }, 30 );
                 setTimeout(function() { $('#modal').css("display","none"); $("#box1").animate({right: '-410px'}); }, 400);
            });
           
        });

        }
```

```css
#modal {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Eurostile";
    src: url('font/Eurostile.ttf');
}
.Eurostile-font {
    font-family: "Eurostile";
}
.btn_modal {
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: darkgrey;
    border: none;
    font-size: 19px;
}
.btn_modal:hover {
    background-color: honeydew;
    color: black;
}
.modal-box {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 20%;
    height: 405px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -410px;
    top: 130px;
    margin-left: -20%;
    z-index: 1000;
    font-family: Eurostile;
}
#modal_form {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.itens {
    margin-left: 10%;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 3%;
    z-index: 10000;
    font-family: Eurostile;
}
.itens input {
    line-height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#bairro {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10%;
    width: 155px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#box {
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 0;
    width: 90%;
    height: 60px;
    resize: none;
    z-index: 10000;
}
#form_title {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
#form_title h3 {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
#modal_form {
    width: 80%;
    height: 400px;
    z-index: 10000;
}
.button {
    width: 160px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: grey;
    color: white;
    z-index: 10000;
    display: block;
    font-family: Eurostile;
}
.button:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
#modal_form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 430px;
}
.cancel {
    margin-right: 2%;
}
.send {
    margin-right: 8%;
}
#cbBox {
    line-height: 10px;
    display: block;
    width: 81%;
    z-index: 10000;
    margin-left: 10%;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
#changeText {
    font-size: 20px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 5%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-family: Eurostile;
}
#align-btn {
    width: 180px;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="modal">
        <div id = "box1" class="modal-box">
            <div class="modal-box-conteudo">

                <form name="contactform" id="modal_form" method="post">
                    <div id="form_title"><p id="changeText">Register for valutation</p></div>  
                   <!-- <select id="cbBox" name="example">
                     <option value="#">I would like a valutation for</option>
                     <option value="A">A</option>
                     <option value="B">A</option>
                     <option value="-">Other</option>
                    </select> -->                
                    <label class="itens">Full name<input class="campo" type="text" name="fullname"></label>
                    <label class="itens">Adress<input class="campo" type="text" name="adress"></label>
                    <label class="itens">Postcode<input class="campo" type="text" name="postcode"></label>
                    <label class="itens">E-mail<input class="campo" type="email" name="email"></label>
                    <label class="itens">Telephone <input class="campo" type="text" name="telefone"></label>
                    <label class="itens">Message <input class="campo" type="text" name="message"></label>
                    <!--<label class="itens">Message<textarea name="conteudo" id="box"></textarea></label>   --> 
                    <div id="align-btn">              
                        <input class="button send" type="submit" value="Send" onclick="return validar();">
                        <input type="button" class="button cancel" value="Cancel">
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá você pode conseguir usando esse feito utilizando CSS Transition e um pouco de JS.

Você deve ter uma classe que sera o container em todo o menu lateral.

```
<div class="menu">
  <button>Toggle</button>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">0001</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">0002</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">0003</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

O Css da classe você deve informar a largura e position relative. No campo left informe a largura do menu multiplicado por -1.

Se seu menu tem 500px left será -500px;

.menu{
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  background:red;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  left: -100px;
}

Dentro do menu você terá o botão que será responsavel ocultar ou nao. 
Este botão será position absolute com uma largura definida e seu right será a largura multiplicada por -1. 
Dessa forma ele fica fora do menu e estará visível quando o menu estiver oculto.

```
button{
  position:absolute;
  width: 50px;
  right: -50px;
}
```

Uma classe .active para exibir o menu

```
.active{
  left: 0px
}
```

Uma função JS que sera responsavel por tratar o click no botão e exibir ou nao o menu.

```
$('button').click(function(){
    if($('.menu').hasClass('active')){
    $('.menu').removeClass('active');
  }else{
    $('.menu').addClass('active');
  }
})
```

Veja esse exemplo funcionando
https://jsfiddle.net/g86p79xd/2/

Answer (score 1):

Olá amigo em vez de usar o modal use a biblioteca [JQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Nela tem o SlideToggle
Faz esse efeito

Baixe a biblioteca e realize o teste.

No HTML

```
<article>
         <figure>
                 <img src="imagem.jpg" alt="img">                    
         </figure>                
       <div>                      
           <h3>Titulo</h3> 
         Seu texto introdução, seu texto introdução, seu texto introdução, seu texto introdução, seu texto introdução, seu texto introdução,
        <div id="new> seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo, seu texto completo. 
        </div>
         <span>
         <a href="javascript:abreFecha('#new')">Saiba mais.</a>
         </span>
 </article>
```

No CSS

```
#new {display:none; margin-top:0px;}
```

No fim do HTML
o JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function abreFecha(sel) {
      $(sel).slideToggle();
      }
      </script>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sidenav_buttons.asp

Aplique este conceito lógico na sua aplicação, não fique preso ao tamanho das divs ou nada do tipo. Depois que você entender este funcionamento tenho certeza que conseguirá resolver seu problema! Grande Abraço!

Comment: obrigado a todos me ajudaram muito